# How to find textfield in nested HTML (Watin) with multiple iframes and tables without knowing anything about names on frames?

Tags: watin

How do I find a textfield by name in deep down in iframes and tables without knowing about the names and I don't even know how many frames it is.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the frames by referencing the Frames property of your browser object, searching each resultant frame for the textbox you're looking for.

**Updated**:

You'll need to find the right frame by source or iterate through them or whatever.  Each frame is seen as its own distinct container of controls; the below code shows this.
Using: IE9, Win7, Watin2.1, NUnit 2.5

Example code

```
IE browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo("http://nunzioweb.com/iframes-example.htm");
Console.WriteLine("exists base: " + browser.Link(Find.ByText("Slick City")).Exists);
Console.WriteLine("in iframe: " + browser.Frame(Find.BySrc("lyrics/455Rocket.html")).Link(Find.ByText("Slick City")).Exists);
```

Output

```
exists base: False
in iframe: True
```

Comment: Ok so there is no way to access the entire html code directly and just search find.byyxxx?
The element I'm looking for is deep down by iframes and tables and the amount of iframes and tables can change often.

Comment: See additional info added to my above answer.